# Java GUI переключение активности окон

Tags: java, swing

Cоздал Dialog:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все было нормально, пока я не решил создать кнопку, при нажатию на которую происходило создание другого фрейма. Он создается и выводится на экран, но он не активен (то есть я не могу работать с ним). Потратил много времени, ничего не вышло. Нужно чтобы всплывающее окно становилось активным, а после закрытия активность переходила в главное окно. `setVisible`, `enable` - не работают.
Почему баттоны на русском(так при добавлении программа создает, я не трогаю)? Кнопка: добавить игрока.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.URL;

public class AA extends JDialog {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton buttonOK;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton отсортироватьButton;
    private JButton найтиButton;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JButton удалитьИгрокаButton;
    private JButton button2;
    private JRadioButton radioButton1;
    private JRadioButton radioButton2;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JButton добавитьИгрокаButton;
    static Manager Mas= new Manager();

    public AA() {
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        setTitle("FtManager");
        FootballMan a = new FootballMan(30,15,"dasd","dasd","dasd",
                "dasd", "dasd", "dasd");
        Mas.Add(a);
        FootballMan b = new FootballMan(15,30,"dasd","dasd","dasd",
                "dasd", "dasd", "dasd");
        Mas.Add(b);
        radioButton1.setSelected(true);
        group.add(radioButton2);
        group.add(radioButton1);
        setLocation(500,260);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setModal(true);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonOK);

        String path = "1.png";
        URL imgURL = AA.class.getResource(path);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        найтиButton.setIcon(icon);

        String path1 = "2.png";
        URL imgURL1 = AA.class.getResource(path1);
        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(imgURL1);
        удалитьИгрокаButton.setIcon(icon1);

        String path3 = "3.png";
        URL imgURL3 = AA.class.getResource(path3);
        ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon(imgURL3);
        button2.setIcon(icon3);

        String path4 = "4.png";
        URL imgURL4 = AA.class.getResource(path4);
        ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon(imgURL4);
        отсортироватьButton.setIcon(icon4);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Все игроки");
                frame.setSize(350,200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(160,300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                JTextArea textAr= new JTextArea();
                Mas.cout(textAr);
                frame.add(textAr);
            }
        });
        отсортироватьButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Mas.sort();
            }
        });
        найтиButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextArea textAr= new JTextArea();
                frame(textAr,"Найденный игрок");
                Mas.search(textField1.getText(),textAr);
            }
        });
        удалитьИгрокаButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Mas.Delete(textField1.getText());
                JTextArea textAr= new JTextArea();
                frame(textAr,"Уменьшенный массив");
                Mas.cout(textAr);
            }
        });


        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean key;
                if(radioButton1.isSelected()==true){
                    key=true;
                }
                else{ key=false;}
                Mas.editing(textField1.getText(),key,textField2);
            }
        });
        textField2.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                textField2.setText(null);
            }
        });

        textField1.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                textField1.setText(null);
            }
        });
       /////////// это событие и должно создать активное окно
        добавитьИгрокаButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JButton but = new JButton("dsas");
                frame.setSize(400,200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(400,400);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public void frame(JTextArea textAr,String title){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(400,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(textAr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AA dialog = new AA();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Были попытки создать не фрейм, а диалог, все так же. Да и к чему? Я знаю, что при создании одиночных фреймов нет проблем с их активностью.

P.S. Я новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возникает сразу несколько вопросов, например, почему Вы наследуетесь от JDialog вместо JFrame и так далее. Но возможно быстрее будет просто указать Вам работающий код, который Вы наполните своими элементами.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        setTitle("Main Frame");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jButton = new JButton("Click Here");
        jButton.addActionListener(s -> {
            new AdditionalFrame();
        });
        add(jButton);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}

class AdditionalFrame extends JFrame {
    public AdditionalFrame() {
        setTitle("Additional Frame");
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }
}
```

При запуске данного приложение откроется `Main Frame` окно с одной единственной кнопкой, по нажатию кнопки будет открыто второе окно `Additional Frame`, которое появится в середине экрана и на который будет установлен фокус и которое будет полностью clickable.

Надеюсь это поможет двигаться дальше.